# ADFS 3.0 with Sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016, adfs

I was wondering if someone could post some advise..

I've setup ADFS with Sharepoint 2016. It all works fine, when browsing to the SharePoint site, it re directs to the ADFS landing page, user can sign in and is redirected to SharePoint.

The issue I'm having is that internal users are also sent to the ADFS landing page when they access sharepoint. Is this normal? I assumed that ADFS would handle the login request by domain credentials and not pass though to ADFS internally.

Have i set something up wrong?

Comment: welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a [Split-DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) environment:

- One Prerequisite: Configure SharePoint with one global URL for internal and external users (e.g. sharepoint.company.com instead of sharepoint.company.local). This will save you a lot of trouble.
- If not already there, create your external Domain (company.com) in your internal DNS (usually ActiveDirectory DNS).
- IMPORTANT: If you create the domain internally, your AD will no longer ask any Internet-DNS for this domain. So if you have a WebPage on www.company.com, it will no longer be reachable! You have to create each record also internally in your AD-DNS and point it to it's correct Internet IP-Address.
- Create an A-Record for "sharepoint" and point it directly to the internal IP-Address of your SharePoint-Server. You completely skip your ADFS-Installation in that way and users will perform SingleSignOn via Kerberos/NTLM
- Your "Internet Domain" should already be configured accordningly, as ADFS from external already works. No change needed here.

Comment: Hi there, I already have an universal domain. My internal domain is .com just like external DNS.

Comment: and i also have an A record for sharepoint. pointing stright at the local IP on the sharepoint server. Internal users still get prompted to sign into adfs

Comment: Can you link an article, which describes your ADFS-Configuration? There are a lot of different implementation-scenarios.

Comment: This is the guide i followed, http://www.dhavalcodes.com/Blog/Configure-SharePoint-Site-to-use-SSL-and-HTTPS

Comment: Ah ok, you configured ADFS with a trusted identity provider. SharePoint will redirect you in that case to ADFS. Could you please update your question on what you want to achieve with your solution? Maybe there is another way than using the TrustedIdentityProvider.

Comment: I didnt think there was any other way of having ADFS work with Sharepoint? We just need external users to access sharpeoint via adfs. The sharepoint server can't be open to the internet so ADFS seemed like a good solution (via a Web Application Proxy ) Should it be done differently? When the user access's sharepoint internally they should be authenticated via their ad credentials and not via the adfs landing page

Comment: You can configure ADFS+WAP to make use of Kerberos Authentication instead of SAML. I prefer Kerberos, even if your configured solution is a little more secure. But SAML also adds a lot of functional drawbacks (you already found one - internal users SSO no longer available). So you have to decide between compatibility (Kerberos) and Security (SAML). Very good Kerberos-ADFS-WAP-Guide: https://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/blog/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy

Comment: So do I just change the authentication to Kerberos in sharepoint? Or do i need to do something on the ADFS too?

Comment: You have to configure Kerberos-Authentication on SharePoint. You have to join your WAP-Server to the AD-Domain. You have to configure your WAP-Application accordingly. And you have to configure Kerberos Constrained delegation. It's described very good in my linked article. And it's absolutely worth the effort :-)